# how do you alias a program whose name conflicts with a built-in while retaining the built-in under a different name?

Tags: terminal, shell, zsh, kill

In zsh 'kill' is a built-in.
I would like to alias killall to kill, as I use 'killall' more often and aliasing it kill would be more convenient. i would like to retain the ability to use kill, however, if possible by aliasing it to 'pidkill' or something of that nature.

How might I accomplish this? or is there a more convenient route i might take that i am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is easily accomplished by aliasing kill to killall. If you want to use kill, simply type '\kill' instead. Starting with a backslash disables aliases. Taking this further to accomplish what you want:

```
alias kill=killall
alias pidkill='\kill'
```

But more to the point, as Nuno Cordeiro said, try not to do it for the same reasons he stated, that too with a command like kill.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: don't do it.

Explanation: Even if you find a way to do it you will be breaking the expected behavior of your system and you will be creating a mental habit for you that will not work on standard systems.

If you really want this then create a new command alias (that doesn't match any built-in) and use that.
Something like kall sounds perfect to me....